# Including a dynamically generated reference in an HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a page with dynamically generated content. In this page there is a form for users to submit questions. How can I include in this form, a reference that is unique to each one of these pages?

```
<div class="detalle-form-wrap">
    <div>
        <h1> 
            Contact us if you are interested!
        </h1>
        <h2>
           REF. VC0171  
       </h2>
    </div>
```

So the reference is dynamically generated inside the `h2` tag. I would like that when a user submits a form, we get that reference as well along with it.

Can use jQuery if necessary.

Comment: Do you just need a unique reference for each submission? If that's the case I would not do it on the client side because someone could submit anything to the form. It would be better to generate it on the server side when submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that code you posted is inside an HTML form, you can use a hidden input field that contains a variable with your reference as a value:

```
<h2>
  REF. VC0171
  <input type="hidden" name="reference_1"  value="<?php echo $reference; ?>">
</h2>
```

That value will be sent with your form on submission, you can get it by its name, like `$reference = $_POST['reference_1'];` (or `$_GET['reference_1'];`, if the form method is `get`)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional `input`-field with `type="hidden"` and set it's `value` to the reference:

```
<input type="hidden" name="reference", value="REF. VC0171" />
```

You can access it just like any other form variable with `$_GET["reference"] or`$_POST["reference"]`. But keep in mind that the user can change the value of it using the developer tools in any browser.